# Easy way of subtracting in javascript to make change

Tags: javascript

I am using this code for my form

```
Total: <input name="total" id="total" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#eee;" value="<? echo $total; ?>" /><br /><br />
Cash: <input name="cash" id="cash" type="text" /><br /><br />
Change: <input name="change" id="change" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#FF0;"/>
```

The total comes from php e.g 25.00, i want to be able to put a number e.g 30.00 in cash and then the change says e.g. 5.00 and i want it to change on key up so if i change the amount it re-calculates,

Can anyone help with the JavaScript to make the calculation work,thanks

Comment: Awesome. What have you tried?

Comment: So, where are you stuck? What difficulty are you having that you'd like us to help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an onchange and onkeyup event handler for the 'cash' element. Then make the calculations in the handler.

Example:

```
Cash: <input name="cash" id="cash" type="text" onkeyup="Recalculate();" onchange="Recalculate()" /><br /><br />
```

In Javascript:

```
function Recalculate()
{
var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").value, 10);
var cash = parseInt(document.getElementById("cash").value, 10);

document.getElementById("change").value = (total-cash);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
Cash: <input name="cash" id="cash" type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()" /><br /><br />
```

JS:

```
function myFunction(){
    var change = document.getElementById("change");
    var cash = document.getElementById("cash").value;
    var total = document.getElementById("total").value;

    change.value = parseInt(cash,10) - parseInt(total,10);      
    }​
```

**[(Working Example)](http://jsfiddle.net/hJDZ5/2/)**

Comment: Thank you, Can you make it work to two decimal places, also is there a way of making the style="background-color:#FF0;" on 'change' change to style="background-color:#900;" if the amount is minus e.g. -2.50 ?